# Overload operator<< for a vector struct of pointer?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, operator-overloading

I am currently trying to make a `overload operator<<`  to my  vector of structs, such that I will print the content of the vector in a matrix format..

this is what I've tried so far

```
// This file is a "Hello, world!" in C++ language by GCC for wandbox.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct element
{
    std::vector<int> keys;
    std::string item;

    element(std::vector <int> key, std::string item)
    {
        keys = key;
        this->item = item;        
    }

};


inline std::stream operator << (std::ostream &stream, const std::vector<element*> _element)
{
    for (auto elements: _element)
    {
        for(auto item : elements)
        {
            std::stream << item.key << " "
        }
    }

}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, Wandbox!" << std::endl;
    std::vector<element> storage;
    std::vector<int> test(10);
    std::generate(test.begin(), test.end(), []() {
    return rand() % 100;
});
    std::string name = "test";
    storage.push_back(element(test,name));
    std::generate(test.begin(), test.end(), []() {
    return rand() % 100;
});
    storage.push_back(element(test,name));
    std::generate(test.begin(), test.end(), []() {
    return rand() % 100;
});
    storage.push_back(element(test,name));

    std::vector<element*> copy_of_storage;
    for(auto elements: storage)
    {
        copy_of_storage.push_back(&(elements));
    }


    std::cout << copy_of_storage << std::endl; 

}
```

but for some reason it is not working, and can't seem to understand what is going wrong?

https://wandbox.org/permlink/BQpqmz0HwoXgyS7t

Comment: Have you tried reading the compiler errors?

Comment: I fixed the compiler errors and the (presumably) typos, and it worked on my machine.  Well, I assume it worked as intended to be working.

Comment: Item in elements is a problem it should be `for(auto item : elements->keys)`

Comment: @JakeFreeman • elements is a pointer, so `for (auto item : elements->keys)`.

Comment: @Eljay fixed you are right, did not notice that

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things that are wrong in your operator<<.

First, your return type should be std::ostream& thus you must return stream. In your second loop :

```
    for(auto item : elements)
```

*elements* is a pointer of element (the value type of your vector) so you can't iterate other it, you might want to iterate other *elements->keys*

Here is your fixed function :

```
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &stream, const  std::vector<element*> _element)
{
    for (auto elements: _element)
        for(auto item : elements->keys)
            stream << item << " ";
    return stream;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/qNYVx2yMg7L76NWe

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things you can do to fix your code example - **better naming conventions** would be an important start.

The reason your code doesn't work is because of your operator << function. The following will work:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &stream, std::vector<element*> _elements)
{
    for (auto element : _elements)
    {
        for(auto item : element->keys)
        {
            stream << item << " ";
        }
    }
    return stream;
}
```

Your working example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/FVXbLlXEAJpVbfAx

*Furthermore:*

- Refactor your code - better variable names.
- Try to use the member initialisation list in the element constructor.
  And might be worth changing the ctor params to const &.
- operator << should return a std::ostream&.
- remove the inline keyword
- in the `operators <<` param list, you can remove the `const` from the `std::vector<element*>` since it is a copy of a vector that contains non-const pointers.